# Qt connecting two signals and one slot

Tags: c++, qt

I have a programm with a QLabel, QTextEdit and a QPushButton.

I want to put the text from LineEdit to Label when I click the button.

I can do that by creating my own slot but can it be done with Qt slots?

I've tried this code but it works not as I want...

```
this->connect(pushButton ,SIGNAL(clicked()), lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
t->connect(lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)) , label ,SLOT(setText(QString)), Qt::DirectConnection);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to force the user to push a QButton for "applying" the text he/she typed in a QTextEdit to a QLabel, maybe you want to check the validity of the inserted text, or use the text to achieve some goal or to store it in a variable for later use... so you need a custom slot or a custom class.

Instead you can connect the signal QTextEdit.textChanged(QString) to the slot QLabel.setText(QString), so everything is typed in the QTextEdit is sent to the QLabel without pushing a button.

But all depends on your aim.

Comment: I know but it's not what i want. I am just wondering if it's posiible do it my way...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

`connect(ui->pushbutton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slot_pushbutton_clicked()))`

And then in the the `slot_pushbutton_clicked` slot,

`ui->label->setText(ui->lineEdit->text)`

Hope it helps :)